# anchor tag generates unwanted height

Tags: html, css, anchor

I am having trouble with unwanted extra height added to the anchor tag.

This is the basic code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<a style="display: inline-block; padding:0; margin:0;">
  <span style="display:inline-block; width:25px; height:25px; background-color: red; padding:0; margin:0;"></span>
  </a>
</body>
</html>
```

and you can test here - http://jsbin.com/cewuza/2/edit

SO how do I remove the unwanted height ? As you can see I have tried modifying the display from *inline* to *inline-block* already.

[image]

[image]

Comment: font-size:0; fixes this on the anchor .. but is it the best practice ?

Comment: What extra height? Your jsbin shows a 25 × 25 px red box. So what is the problem? Your screen shots are about something different. Please post code that actually reproduces the issue and specify exactly what the issue is.

Comment: check the anchor tag.. not the span itself it shows 29px

Comment: http://cl.ly/image/1Z0q2L2i1z2D

Comment: add vertical-align: top to the 'a' tag, and you should be good to go; the extra spaces comes from using display: inline-block

Comment: @digitalzoomstudio, you should edit the question so that it explicitly says what you regard as the problem, and you should remove irrelevant screen shots. The question itself should be fully understandable on its own.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following demonstrates what the problem actually is:

```html
<a style="display: inline-block; outline: solid blue;">
  <span style="display:inline-block; width:25px; height:25px; background-color: red;"></span>
</a>
```

The `span` element sits on the text baseline, since an inline block behaves like a big (or maybe small) text character. There is some space below the baseline, for descenders of letters like j, g, and q.

To fix this, make the inline block aligned to the bottom of its parent element, using the [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property:

```html
<a style="display: inline-block; outline: solid blue;">
  <span style="vertical-align: bottom; display:inline-block; width:25px; height:25px; background-color: red;"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

try `font-size: 0;` on the anchor

edit: didn't see the question comments..

Comment: It looks like the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999522/anchor-tag-generates-unwanted-height#comment44388384_27999522) you are referring to was wondering "but is it the best practice ?"